# Toggle block menu with Redux?

Tags: angular, redux

I have a some block components that contains another components like this:

```
<app-block *ngFor="let block of blocks">
   <div class="header"></div>
   <div class="content">
      <app-list></app-list>
   </div>
</app-block>
```

I need to toggle `.content` after click on `.header` then to be able open one of blocks by default. For example the third. Also after closing block I need to notify the component in another Angular module. Not children component.

I think about applying Redux to set default/open/closed states. It is good choice?

Comment: You have to manage the state of your component in some way. This could be directly inside your component, in a service or in a full-fledged store solution (e.g. NgRx). Which to use depends on the complexity of your app and the complexity of your state.
Redux adds quite some complexity that needs justification. On the other hand if you just want to store a simple flag or something doing so in the component might be sufficient.

Comment: So, I mean who should know that the third component must be opened?

Comment: The parent component for `app-block`

Comment: Should I write the same Redux actions/reducers for each blocks `<app-block>` to show/hide them?

Comment: Could you explan me, when I get data from server I must put in in storage Redux, right? Then I can get this in parent component and display all blocks component in block. But how to open the second block by default?

Comment: Right, put your data in the storage, then simply select it and render.
To be able to open the second block, you can either determine the default box at moment when you get data from server and store in the storage or save some info about default box for example id.

Comment: So, it is another state,  right? Could you share an little exmaple about opening second block, I dont understand for own block own state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically the logic is to store opened boxes ids in the array.

Dispatch the box id that needs to be opened.

In the reducer we will toggle opened/closed boxes by filtering or pushing box id.

After that you can select the `openedBlocks` from state and use in the component

This enables to have multiple boxes opened at the same time. In case you want to have one box opened at time you will need to introduce another property which stores opened box info but not array.

```js
interface BlockModel {
  id: number;
}

// actions 
export const openedBlock = createAction(
  'Opened Box',
  props < {
    boxId: id
  } > ()
);

// state
export const initialBlocksState = {
  blocks: BoxModel[],
  openedBlocks: number[]
  defaultBlock: null,
};

// helpers
function toggleArrayItem(arr, boxId) {
  return arr.includes(boxId) ?
    arr.filter(id => id !== boxId) // remove box
    :
    [...arr, boxId]; // add box
}

// reducer
const blocksReducer = createReducer(
  initialBlocksState,
  // listen openedBlock action
  on(openedBlock, (state, {
    boxId
  }) => {


    // returns new array with toggled boxes
    const openedBlocks = toggleArrayItem(state.openedBlocks, boxId);

    // return new state
    return {
      ...state,
      openedBlocks

    };
  }),

);
```

If you want have own state for each block you can use advantage of Object Literal.

But you will need to first serialize state and provide another actions
that will update property in desired block

```js
// models
interface BlockModel {
  id: number;
  opened: true;
  default: false;
}

interface BlocksState {
  id: BlockModel;
}
// state
export const initialBlocksState = {
  blocksState: BlockState
}
// helpers 
function serializeBlocks(blocks: BlocksModel[]): BlockState {
  return blocks.reduce((acc, block) => {
    acc[block.id] = block;
    return acc;
  }, {});
}
// reducer
const blocksReducer = createReducer(
  initialBlocksState,
  on(loadAllBlocks, (state, { blocks }) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      blocksState: serializeBlocks(blocks)
    };
  }),

);
```

Comment: Thank you for extended answer! I will elaborate this!

Comment: How to add block to storage? Because now I get block in loop: <app-block *ngFor="let block of blocks"> And block it is a component

Comment: Blocks are created by anothr model, in my case it use categories list

Comment: What is it: `loadAllBlocks`?

Comment: I have no idea what your application looks like, I just provided some examples how you can handle some cases. To add block element to the storage you need on click pass that block into the method where dispatch action and handle in the reducer

Comment: https://ngrx.io/ you can check out NgRx state management

Comment: Only one question, how to colelcti all block in one and push to storage?

Comment: Let imaging I have list of users, inside groups: `let groups = [{id:1, users: []}]`

Comment: It's not clear for me what shape of  data you want to store and how